# starting and stopping a jar from jenkins

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, jenkins, executable-jar

I've been working on my jenkins server off and on for the last few weeks. Right now it runs fine building and outputting the files to a remote location. However, i'm looking to do some pass or fail tests on the files before they are uploaded. This way i avoid releasing broken versions of my work. As well avoid more bug reports that i do not need to be reading.

The files i'm looking to run are actually plugins for another program. So i need to actually start this program as i can configure all the files before hand. The program is a .jar file which i know i can launch using a bat of shell script. The issue is i don't know at this point how to terminate the .jar program after it has been running. All the solutions i've found require me to modify the jar to terminate itself, or kill the JVM. Both i can't due for varies reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It been a year since i asked this question but i found a much nicer way to solve this question. Its called JUnit and is a testing lib for java. With it i don't need to launch the entire jar but can test peace by peace at a time. As well if require i can write a test to launch the entire .jar file. In the test i can check if files exist, if functions complete correctly, and if any error is thrown during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It's a heavy hack, but you can make a shell script start a background thread that checks if the JVM is done, then terminate it.

Rudimentary example in bash:

```
start_jvm_command >>console.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
while ! grep 'done signal' console.log; do sleep 1; done
pkill -f "regexp for start_jvm_command"
```

Note: I was using pkill to terminate to avoid wrapper shell scripts.

Comment: hmm i'll try this a bit later, but how does this exactly work? Does the JVM send the done signal when the program is fully launched, or after the program closes? I don't know much on the subject of the inter workings of the JVM sadly.

Comment: This approach has nothing to do with jvm. You could start anything with this. The point of the above script is to stop a server (see pkill command in third line) once certain criteria is met (second line, at the moment grep would see if a certain line is present in the server output). The server itself is started in the background in the first line. If unsire I recommend reading up on shell scripting a bit; it's well worth the time.

Comment: I'm slowly working my way threw learning scripting, but don't have the time right now to learn what i need. Also were would i find a list of conditions i can use for the second line, just in case "done signal" doesn't cover my needs. Also thank you for your time.